# Copy field from table to the same table the same colum

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Here's the table header

**teacher_id | day_id | room**

I want to copy room where **day_id="1"** to other days so each teacher will have for each day a room number he had at day_id "1".

Ho do I keep track of teacher_id and not mess things up?

Thank you

Alex

Comment: What database server are you using? Postgres? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example how you can copy all rows in day 1 to day 2. You could iterate for all days.

```
INSERT INTO table (teacher, day_id, room)
SELECT  teacher, '2', room
FROM    table
WHERE day_id='1'
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer!

Comment: How can I adjust this query to use Update statement instead of insert?